# Fill missing values in Pandas DataFrame plot

Tags: python, pandas

I've got the following pandas DataFrame :

```
      Month      val  count
0     1           A      1
1     1           M      1
2     2           M      2
3     3           B      3
4     3           M      5
5     5           B      1
```

Using pivot by val like this :

```py
# Pivot by val
df.pivot(index='Month', columns='val',values='count').fillna(0).plot(marker='o', figsize=(14,5))

# Plot configuration
plt.title("Number of monthly searches for A, M and B")
plt.xlabel("Month")
plt.xticks(arange(12), calendar.month_abbr[1:13], rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

The following plot is obtained :
[image]

The problem is that only values for the range of months in the dataframe are filled. Is it possible to fill with 0 the rest of values (months) outside the range ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reindex` -

```
df.pivot(index='Month', columns='val',values='count').reindex(range(1,13)).fillna(0)
```

`reindex` will insert more rows and then `fillna(0)` fills all `na` values with 0. If you plot after that, it will do the trick.

Warning: All colors won't be distinctly visible!

```
# Pivot by val
df.pivot(index='Month', columns='val',values='count').reindex(range(1,13)).fillna(0).plot(marker='o', figsize=(14,5))

# Plot configuration
plt.title("Number of monthly searches for A, M and B")
plt.xlabel("Month")
plt.xticks(arange(12), calendar.month_abbr[1:13], rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i've finally used `reindex(arange(12))` since `range(1,13)` left Jan empty.